# Keyboard shortcut to switch between Activity Monitor tabs?

Tags: keyboard, activity-monitor

Are there keyboard shortcuts to switch between or select specific Activity Monitor View, e.g. CPU, Memory, Energy, Disk & Network?

[image]

Use case example, instead of clicking with the mouse, it'd be nice to toggle between two Views while examining a specific process like Opera, Chrome helper, bash, etc. Instead or mousing around between the view tabs, it'd be faster to use a keyboard shortcut to toggle between and check the process CPU and Memory loads:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that actually. It's better to see both things at the same time - that's why you can add new columns to the current view. Just click `View` -> `Columns` and choose the one you need. You can also drag them around.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was not aware that I could add/edit columns to the different views :)